# Create a dotted pairs list from a list dividing its pairs numbers between another number

Tags: list, scheme

I have the following list:

```
(define lista '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3)))
```

I want to divide each of the numbers on pairs (1, 2 and 3) by another number in the following variable:

```
(define sum 6)
```

And I want to change that result into each pairs to get a list like this one:

```
'((a . 1.66667) (b . 0.33333) (c . 0.5)))
```

I have tried these sentences:

```
(map / cdr lista sum)
```

and

```
(map / (cdr lista) sum)
```

and

```
(map / (map cdr lista) sum)
```

But, in all cases there is a problem with parameter `sum` in `map` function: a list is expected.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit trickier than it seems. You need to create a new pair, as (normally) you cannot modify an existing pair, and anyway `map` returns a new list:

```
; returns a new list
#lang racket
(map (lambda (p) (cons (car p) (/ (cdr p) sum)))
     lista)
```

In case you're supposed to modify the existing pairs with `set-cdr!`, then you should use `for-each` instead of `map`, and change to a language that supports pair mutation:

```
; modifies list in-place
#lang r5rs
(for-each (lambda (p) (set-cdr! p (/ (cdr p) sum)))
          lista)
```

I don't really think you're expected to mutate data in-place yet, so I'd go with my first proposed solution, which is the idiomatic one.

Comment: What does #lang r5rs mean? I'm using Scheme in DrRacket and I need to set #lang racket to run the programs.

Comment: That means that you have to use `r5rs`, a different language (not Racket) to mutate pairs. Don't worry about my second answer, it's probably not what you need at the moment. I added it for completeness' sake.

Comment: The language is defined at the top of the file, and works as long as you've selected "determine language from source" in the bottom-left corner or the window.

Comment: Thanks. Is Racket the same language than Scheme, or are they different languages?

Comment: They're different languages :) at the core they share a lot of common ground but they differ in some subtle ways, for instance, in the way they handle mutation. Racket is a more modern, pragmatic dialect of Scheme. They're also different in their built-in libraries and procedures, Racket is richer in this area.